# Calling docker from Spark EMR job

Tags: emr, amazon-emr

I have an executable that I've wrapped in a docker image. I need to invoke it from my spark job, wait for it to generate an output file, and then load that file into an RDD.

Should I use the `pipe` method? How do I ensure that docker is available on the EMR master?

Comment: where is the docker image located relative to the emr cluster? you could import a docker API package. https://github.com/docker/docker-py etc The big thing you'd need to figure out is security groups for both the cluster and the VM containing your docker images... if they're not together in the cluster.